# How do I hide the textbox if either select option box is selected

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
<div class="flex w-full">
            <select placeholder="Sort By" v-model="criminal.sortBy" class="bg-grey-lightest border p-2 border-gray mr-4 h-10 w-1/2 rounded-sm font-basic mt-2 mb-4">
                <option>----------------------------</option>
                <option value="1">Most Wanted</option>
                <option value="2">Last Seen</option>
                <option value="3">Very Popular</option>
                <option value="4">Sort By Bounty/Reward</option>
            </select>

            <select placeholder="Country of Origin" v-model="criminal.country" class="bg-grey-lightest border p-2 border-gray mr-4 h-10 w-full rounded-sm font-basic mt-2 mb-4">
                <option >--------------</option>
                @foreach ($countries as $country)
                <option value="{{  $country->id }}">{{ $country->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <p class="font-bold text-md">or</p>


        <div class="flex">
            <input  v-show="criminalName = true" placeholder="Search by Name" type="text" v-model="criminal.name" class="bg-grey-lightest border p-2 border-gray mr-4 h-10 w-full rounded-sm font-basic mt-2 mb-4">
        </div>
```

So this would display this

[image]

I need some help.. I want to hide the textbox if either one of the select box is selected

so if the first select box is selected.. then hide the textbox.. that's it

```
data () {
        return {    
            criminalName : false , 
            criminal :{ 
                sortBy: "",
                country: null,
                name : "",
                state: ""
            },
            group : { 
                name : "",
                country : "",
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `v-model` of the select elements are `criminal.sortBy` and `criminal.country` respectively, you can show the input element if neither has a value set:

```vue
<input v-show="criminalName && !criminal.sortBy && !criminal.country">
```

You had `criminalName = true` originally which is incorrect, I think you meant `criminalName === true`, which can be simplified to just `criminalName`.